# ¿Cómo reemplazar un caracter en un String?

Tags: java, string, intellij-idea

Estoy trabajando con el precio de Bitcoin en un String y para pasarlo a Double necesito deshacerme de la coma que marca los miles (espero que eso tenga sentido).
He probado con el método replace pero no consigo el resultado que quiero.
Esto es lo que he probado:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String number = "10,000.32";
        number.replaceAll(",","");
        System.out.println(number);
    }

}
```

Pero el resultado me queda igual que el primer String

¿Algún consejo?
Muchas gracias

Comment: Debes entender que los objetos String son inmutables: cualquier cambio siempre significa crear una nueva instancia

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prueba:

```
number = number.replaceAll(",","");
```

El método `replaceAll` devuelve string, debes asignarlo a tu variable para que tenga efecto.

Aunque esto es perfectamente válido yo te recomendaría usar java.text.DecimalFormat:

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(new Locale("en", "UK"));
decimalFormat.applyPattern("###,###.##");

try {
    Number d = decimalFormat.parse(number);
    System.out.println(d);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Genial, muchísimas gracias